# Campos dinâmicos usando Sinatra

Tags: ruby, formulário, sinatra

Em Rails essa é uma tarefa relativamente simples. Mas não encontrei nada na documentação do Sinatra que afirme isso ser possível. Quero adicionar campos a um formulário dinamicamente. Usuário clica em um link e um novo campo é adicionado. Caso deseje, clica em outro link e o campo é removido. No front-end a tarefa é super tranquila, eu sei. Mas e pra persistir um número arbitrário de campos no banco de dados? Como seria?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, cada campo adicionado será um *registro* e não uma *coluna* de uma tabela, correto? Isso não ficou muito claro.

Answer (score 1):

A documentação diz que o Sinatra também suporta *query parameters* opcionais:

> Routes may also utilize query parameters:
>
> ```
> get '/posts' do
>   # matches "GET /posts?title=foo&author=bar"
>   title = params[:title]
>   author = params[:author]
>   # uses title and author variables; query is optional to the /posts route
> end
> ```
>
> Fonte: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

Assim você consegue usar um `if` simples para descobrir se um parâmetro existe:

```
require "sinatra"

get "/foo" do
  params[:bar] if params[:bar]
end
```

No exemplo acima:

```
localhost:5678/foo            # retorna uma página em branco
localhost:5678/foo?bar=foobar # retorna "foobar"
```

Assim creio que um jeito de resolver o teu problema seria criar cada campo com um número atrás:

```html
<input type="text" name="campo1"/>
<input type="text" name="campo2"/>
<input type="text" name="campo3"/>
<input type="text" name="campo4"/>
```

E então você poderia utilizar um laço de repetição para verificar se o campo existe e faz o que precisar com ele.